# web scraping selenium find elements by class name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to extract the all the products data from this page:

[https://www.shufersal.co.il/online/he/קטגוריות/סופרמרקט/חטיפים%2C-מתוקים-ודגני-בוקר/c/A25](https://www.shufersal.co.il/online/he/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%98/%D7%97%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D%2C-%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%93%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%A8/c/A25)

I want to get all the `li` tag with the name class `miglog-prod miglog-sellingmethod-by_unit`

like this:

```html
<li class="miglog-prod miglog-sellingmethod-by_unit" data-product-name="צדפים דגנים בטעם שוקולד" data-entry-number=""
data-product-box
data-product-replace=""
data-product-price="12.9"
data-product-purchasable="false"
data-food="true"
data-selling-method="BY_UNIT"
data-product-code="P_7296073442226">
```

I tried:

```py
shufersal = "https://www.shufersal.co.il/online/he/קטגוריות/סופרמרקט/חטיפים%2C-מתוקים-ודגני-בוקר/c/A25"

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    
import time
driver.get(shufersal)
for i in range(0,5): # here you will need to tune to see exactly how many scrolls you need
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 400)')
    time.sleep(1)
products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("miglog-prod miglog-sellingmethod-by_unit")
    
print(products)
```

but I don't find any product:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you can do:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

products = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
    By.CSS_SELECTOR,
    ".miglog-prod.miglog-sellingmethod-by_unit"
)
```

or,

```py
products = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    "li.miglog-prod.miglog-sellingmethod-by_unit"
)
```

Note that in the first method, I am passing just the class names, but in second one I am passing even the element (`li`).

(Edit: Ok, I checked on REPL, I get elements even if I don't pass `li` so I am not sure about the behaviour here. Btw, I tested this for Firefox.)

From what I read, you dont get products is because `find_elements_by_class_name` needs only one class name and you have passed two..